# App for analyzing installers

Tags: applications, install, utilities

Is there an app which shows contents of a .pkg file and shows which files an installer copies to my mac, what scripts it runs and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a shareware app called [**`Pacifist`**](http://www.charlessoft.com/) ($20).  I've used it for years, and it works wonderfully well (even on old Macs).

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can download a free QuickLook extension for blazing fast previews of packages.  It's called [**`SuspiciousPackage`**](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/).

[image]

Comment: I see this was edited to say that Pacifist is shareware, but you can use it for an indefinite period of time without purchasing the software.  In a sense it's nagware.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract package files and sort through their contents without actually installing them. To do this, you can often just right-click on a `.pkg` file and select “Show Package Contents” – but that isn’t always displayed.

If that option is unavailable, you can extract `.pkg` files using a command line tool called `pkgutil` that is bundled with OS X. Launch Terminal.app and enter the following:

```
pkgutil --expand /path/to/package.pkg /output/destination/
```

Hint: you can drag & drop items into the Terminal to print their full path, making this tip easier by typing: `pkgutil –expand [drop file here] /destination/path/`.

After that, you can go to the output path in the Finder and check out the extracted files.

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/26/show-package-contents-unavailable-extract-pkg-files-without-installing-them/)