# What is "ss_conn_service " running on OS X?

Tags: macos, imac, launchd, activity-monitor, root

I'm using OS X El Capitan on iMac 21.5". As an experienced user, I follow activity monitor sometimes for security of my device. For 2-3 days,"**ss_conn_service**" is running on my device. I cannot determine what the process do. I suspect from a Galaxy Tab which I plugged to my device 2-3 days ago. Did you encountered with this process ?

**Sample of the process obtained from Activity Monitor:**

> Analysis of sampling ss_conn_service (pid 62) every 1 millisecond
>   Process:         ss_conn_service [62] Path:
>   /Library/LaunchAgents/ss_conn_service Load Address:    0x100000000
>   Identifier:      ss_conn_service Version:         ??? Code Type:
>   X86-64 Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2015-11-20 15:09:20.236 +0200 Launch Time:
>   2015-11-20 10:30:28.221 +0200 OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.1
>   (15B42) Report Version:  7 Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Thanks.

Comment: A Google search shows it to be the Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones.

Comment: Yes. However, search reports show only Windows driver information. Is there any drawback available for deleting this app from system ?

Comment: I would look at the .plist files in `/Library/LaunchAgents` to see the one that's loading "ss_conn_service" and see what the path to the "ss_conn_service" executable is.  This might provide additional information to help determine the source.  As to deleting it, if it is for your phone then if you don't plan on connecting your phone to the computer again then deleting it shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'm going to assume there is an implied question here "How can I tell what package installed X" - if you have another question, you could ask a follow on question or edit this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delete it from `/Library/LaunchAgents`. Now, everything is going well. I don't encountered any problem right now. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Going into a general, here's how you analyze any arbitrary file is too broad for this site, but you can pretty easily determine if something is part of the core OS by searching for the file amongst the receipts:

Use a tool like Pacifist to [check for the file in question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123845/5472) as part of the system receipts:

- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

As you get more used to checking on things, you can also use these tools to look at what a specific installer is going to do instead of just running it.

- [App for analyzing installers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/app-for-analyzing-installers)

One last trick, you can also use `tmutil compare` if you have time machine to see what files changed between one interval and another. I would recommend doing this for small time periods when you don't think much is changing. Typically, thousands of files change each hour - so you'll need to get used to weeding out the "false" positives.